# jQuery Expand/Collaspe DIV not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, expand

I am trying to Expand/Collapse a `DIV`. I am using a function to pass in the height I want it set to but it is not expanding or collapsing the `DIV`. Does anyone have any idea on what I have done wrong? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A9fdd/)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.podTitles{
    float:left;
    clear:none;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#3A3938;
    line-height:23px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function changeheight(heightval) {
            var heightset = heightval + 'px';
            if(this.text == 'more')
            {
                $('#overviewtext').animate({ 'height': heightset }, 600);
                $(this).text($(this).text() == 'more' ? 'less' : 'more');
            }
            else if(this.text == 'less')
            {
                $('#overviewtext').animate({ 'height': '150px' }, 600);
                $(this).text($(this).text() == 'more' ? 'less' : 'more');
            }

        };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-image:url('Images/RedPodHeader.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; width: 360px; height:23px; background-color: red;">
<span class="podTitles">Overview</span>
<span style="float: right; padding-right: 10px;"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="changeheight(250);"id="morelink">more</a></span>
</div>
<div style="height: 150px; width: 338px; padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid silver; border-left: 1px solid silver; border-right: 1px solid silver;" id="overviewtext"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't find any inclusion of jQuery in your code.... You're not loading jQuery!

Comment: @poscaman forgot to add that line, when I was copying it over. But in the jsfiddle it does load jquery and it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of changes in your script, **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/zeKKe/)** here

```
function changeheight(heightval, _this) {
    var heightset = heightval + 'px';
    var thisText = $(_this).text() ;
    if (thisText == 'more') {
        $('#overviewtext').animate({
            'height': heightset
        }, 600);
        $(_this).text((thisText  == 'more') ? 'less' : 'more');
    }
    else if (thisText  == 'less') {

        $('#overviewtext').animate({
            'height': '150px'
        }, 600);

        $(_this).text((thisText  == 'more') ? 'less' : 'more');
    }

    return false;
};
```

Markup change - added this as an argument to the fxn call,

```
onclick="return changeheight(250, this);"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `this` as a parameter to the `changeheight` function in order to use it. So it would be something like `changeheight(250, this)`. Your function declaration then would be `function changeheight(heightval, that) . . .` where `that` would then refer to the link that calls the function. You still have some other problems, (I think `.text` should be `.innerHTML`), but that should get you on the right track.